# What is the variance $V(X)$?

Tags: probability

> A person has $4$ keys from which only one opens the door.
>
> He puts away each one that does not open it.
>
> $X$ is the number of tries to open the door.
>
> 1. What is the law of $X$?
> 2. Compute $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$
>
>    ---

1. Law of $X$:

\begin{array}{c|lcr}
X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
P(X) & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & 1 \\
\end{array}

Is it correct?

2. $E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{4} X_iP(X_i) = \frac{77}{12}$

I am not sure about the variance. Am I going to need the formula: $V(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$?

Thank you.

Comment: Your Law of X is wrong. Each key should have a equal probability of opening the door. You can see the the mean no. of key required is 6.something. For calculating the probabity of 2nd key opening the door, you must consider that the first key must fail. $P(2)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}$.First key failing * second key succeeding.

Comment: Your answer to (1.) is incorrect - as you can see the sum of the probabilities exceeds 1. p(1) = 1/4 is correct. For two tries, you need to fail the first trial, so p(2) = (1-1/4) x (1/3) etc. Once you get part (1) done, it appears you know how to do part (2).

Comment: @Dean $p(X=3) = (1 - p(X=1)) (1 - p(X = 3)). \frac{1}{3} $ and 

$p(X = 4) = (1 - p(X=1)) (1 - p(X = 2)) (1 - p(X = 3)) . \frac{1}{4}$. Is is correct? Thank you.

Comment: @NetravatPendsey $p(X=3) = (1 - p(X=1)) (1 - p(X = 2)). \frac{1}{3} $and $p(X = 4) = (1 - p(X=1)) (1 - p(X = 2)) (1 - p(X = 3)) . \frac{1}{4}$. Is it correct?

Comment: @NetravatPendsey For the last $p(X=4) = (1 - p(X=1)) (1 - p(X = 2)) (1 - p(X = 3)) . \frac{1}{4}$, we multiply by $\frac{1}{4}$ and not $1$. Right?

Comment: @ZouhairElYaagoubi No. We multiply by 1 because there is no chance that the key wouldn't work.

Comment: @NetravatPendsey Thank you so much for your help. =)